# Select2: Getting formatSelection to have a certain context

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I've made a very simple wrapper for Select2 (which really helps) and am having trouble making use of the `formatSelection` field. For instance, I init the Select2 through my wrapper like so:

```
this.elem.select2({
    allowClear : options.allowClear ? true : false,
    placeholder : options.placeholder ? options.placeholder : undefined,
    createSearchChoice : !options.preventNew ? this.newEntry : undefined,
    formatSelection : this.formatSelection,
    data : this.data
});
```

However, the problem is that when `this.formatSelection` is called (and it is), `this` refers to the Select2 instance and not my wrapper. Anyone have any ideas for how I can get select2 to call my function with the "correct" context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the `this` context explicity. Reason is `this` context is set as the context of the caller (except for bound functions), and your function is a callback that gets invoked from within the select plugin, so naturally the context withing `formatSelection` will be of that of the `select2` and not your plugin instance.

```
this.elem.select2({
    allowClear : options.allowClear ? true : false,
    placeholder : options.placeholder ? options.placeholder : undefined,
    createSearchChoice : !options.preventNew ? this.newEntry : undefined,
    formatSelection : this.formatSelection.bind(this), //<-- here
    data : this.data
});
```

Since you are using jquery you can use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) as well

```
formatSelection : $.proxy(this.formatSelection,this)
```

Comment: Well, that was MUCH easier than I expected :) Thanks!